# Android ConnectivityManager is error 'unreachable statement'

Tags: java, android, connectivity, unreachable-statement

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_recipe_list, container, false);

    ConnectivityManager connMgr =
            (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

}
```

I write the code in Fragment but it makes error unreachable statement

```
public void updateConnectedFlags() {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr =
            (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
}
```

so, I move the code in method, but there is no error. Why?

Comment: Your first line of `onCreateView` you return so the method exits. Hence all following code will never be reached. Perhaps you have a misplaced brace

Comment: ahhh...     thank you !!